# BootStrap navbar-collapse button is not work on clicking

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to bootStrap trying to create a navigation bar. I want the menu items to be shown in a dropdown list when the window size is resized below a certain level. My menu items do collapse on resizing the window but on clicking the navbar-collapse button no drop down list is shown.
Any help is appreciated. I have commented the spot as "The following div doesn't open in the drop down menu" in code snippet where I'm having trouble

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->

<!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">--> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 


<style type="text/css">
 .my{
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border:solid grey;
 }
 
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="navbar navbar-default"> 
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">MB's Website</a>
    
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button> 
    
    </div>
  <!--The following div doesn't open in the drop down menu-->
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>     
    </ul>
    
   </div> 
  </div>

 </div>

 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 my">content</div>
 </div>

 <div><p> </p></div>

  


 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
 </div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min."></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files
as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->

<!--<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">--> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 


<style type="text/css">
 .my{
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border:solid grey;
 }
 
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="navbar navbar-default"> 
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">MB's Website</a>
    
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" datatoggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button> 
    </div>
   
   <!--The following div doesn't open in the drop down menu-->
   
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>     
    </ul>
    
   </div> 
  </div>

 </div>

 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 my">content</div>
 </div>

 <div><p> </p></div>

  


 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
 </div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min."></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files
as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou

Comment: You have a wrong data attribute, it should be `data-toggle`, not `datatoggle`.

Comment: load jquery above bootstrap js file and you are using bootstrap 3 style and bootstrap 4 javascript

Comment: so please use the correct version of bootstrap js and css file together

Answer (score 0):

Use correct version files of bootstrap.Do not mix together the versions , that means if you are using Bootstrap 3 use correct css js files of that version

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initialscale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style type="text/css">
 .my{
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  border:solid grey;
 }
 
</style>

</head>
<body>

 <div class="navbar navbar-default"> 
  <div class="container">
   <div class="navbar-header">
    <a href="" class="navbar-brand">MB's Website</a>
    
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
     <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button> 
    </div>
   
   <!--The following div doesn't open in the drop down menu-->
   
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="">About</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>     
    </ul>
    
   </div> 
  </div>

 </div>

 <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-6 my">content</div>
 </div>

 <div><p> </p></div>

  


 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 my">content</div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```